# Referencing lua table/object after script has been run

Tags: c++, user-interface, lua, scripting

I'm designing a GUI system in Lua, bound to C++. I won't go into unnecessary detail here, but essentially the lua script that creates a form looks something like:

```
local objectTwo = Gui:newObject{
    position = {10,10},
    size = {100,100},
}

local objectOne = Gui:newObject{
    position = {10,10},
    size = {100,100},
    handleOnClick = function(x, y, button)
        objectTwo:setProperties{
            hidden = false
        }
    end
}
```

Essentially newObject passes the table into C++ and handleOnClick is turned into a custom C++ function class. When that object is clicked, it calls that function class and it's evaluated in Lua.

However, objectTwo no longer exists in Lua, since the script has run, so it tries to call setProperties on nil and crashes.

My question is, how do I ensure that objectTwo can still be referenced in handleOnClick? I would prefer not to put it in a global registry or some such, to avoid polluting the namespace.

Is there something I could do with a closure?

Answer (score 0):

When the `objectOne` is being constructed, the `local objectTwo` variable is not in the scope yet, so Lua assumes reading from global variable `objectTwo`, which is never defined, so returns `nil` when read.

At least move the `local objectTwo` declaration before the code that will reference it. You don't have to define the object right there, assignment can be performed later. But variable declaration must precede the code that wants to access it.

Also pay attention to the ownership over the data/code. You said you 'convert it to custom C++ class' without extra details. You should be aware that you must store the Lua value for the callback function somewhere. Be it registry, or some class-owned table, but still stored somewhere reachable to Lua, so the callback function won't be garbage-collected at some moment later.

Comment: Ah yeah, I wrote it wrong. I've edited it to reflect that objectTwo is indeed declared before objectOne... It seems like objectTwo is still going out of scope somehow.

The objects are converted to C++ by using the registry. I've made sure they aren't garbage collected until C++ code destructs the C++ object that refers to the lua object.

Comment: @KingCoyote `objectTwo` can't be GC'ed until function in `handleOnClick` is collected. The `objectTwo` is in callback's lexical closure. Do you store `objectOne` somewhere? It's local to the script's chunk, and if it's not stored somewhere else, it will be gc'ed, and your c++ destructors will cleanup everything else (if properly done), including callback function, so `objectTwo` will be cleaned too.

Comment: objectTwo and objectOne are both stored in the registry as refs that belong to two separate c++ objects. The callback function reference is also stored in the same c++ object that holds the reference to objectOne.

Comment: @KingCoyote Final C++ objects are in the registry. What about the input arguments to `Gui:newObject` ? Those tables with argument, how do you proceed with the data in it? The callback is a Lua object, not just the pointer to some code. It must be saved in Lua - in registry, or nested in object-owned table that's stored in registry.

Comment: Yep, the function Gui:newObject in C++ takes the input table and refs it, storing it in C++. This same table is returned by newObject back into lua. Essentially, the C++ object holds a reference to the table passed into newObject and that is also returned by the function into lua so it can be used elsewhere.

The whole table, with size, position, and handleOnClick function, is ref'd and stored in C++.